# Get item positions in string array android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
String[] = {
    "#abc #def",
    "#abc",
    "#def",
    "#xyz #def"
}
```

My question is I want to search for specific character or string like "#abc" or "a" and get their positions in the array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just loop through it and check each string yourself

```
for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++)
    if(array[i].contains("#abc"))
        aPosition = i;
```

If you want to store multiple positions, you'll need a mutable array of some sort such as a `List`, so instead of `aPosition = i` you'll have `list.add(i)`

Comment: That doesn't answer my question then. That's what I needed. To store all positions in an array

Comment: that list.add(i) seems to be pretty good thing. Gimme a sec to test it. And yes, I know Java but this isn't thing I am very familiar with

Comment: Basically I found out that putting the values into the list isn't neccessary because I wanted just to put the values into listview.

Answer (score 6):

```
String[] values = { "1a", "2a", "3a"};
int pos = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(values)).indexOf("3a");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let's call your array of strings s, the code will be:
String[] s={"#abc #def",
            "#abc",
            "#def",
            "#xyz #def"};
int count=0;
    for(String s1:s){
if(s1.contains("#abc")){
//do what ever you want
System.out.println("Found at: "+count);
break;
}
count++;
}
```

hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `indexOf`

```
String[] myList = {
            "#abc #def",
            "#abc",
            "#def",
            "#xyz #def"
           };
int index = myList.indexOf("#abc");
```

and in the `index` variable you become the index of the searched element in your array

Comment: yeah, that will return one number but I want all index nubers that have that string in them

Comment: "Cannot invoke indexOf(String) on the array type String[]"

Comment: indexOf doesn't exist

Answer (score -1):

you can use ArrayUtils

```
String[] myList = { "#abc #def", "#abc", "#def", "#xyz #def" };
int index =  ArrayUtils.indexOf(myList,"#def");
```

Comment: in this case using for loop is better solution because there are more indexes that have specific string not just one

Comment: and there doesn't appear to be a method .indexOf for ArrayUtils